# Pygame joystick doesn't show multiple joysticks

Tags: pygame, joystick

I am using a Thrustmaster's F/A-18C Hornet with HOTAS Magnetic Base, and an APEM USB Thumbstick, both of them are connected to Raspberry Pi 3, the issue I am having is that the pygame only recognize 1 of them at a time, any idea how can I solve this issue, the `pygame.joystick.get_count()` only gives output of 1.

Comment: Do you get this problem *only* with PyGame?

Comment: I only used pygame, funno if there is another library I could use to find the Thumbstick